# How can i log my login in ubuntu?

Tags: login, password, log

I had an idea a day when i try to calculate my work time in computer, to see the time that i start to use my computer and finish. But in a day, i ended up missing my work password with my personal computer password, and i started to thinking in other functionality.

If i create a log file with all username and password that i put in login to access my computer using ubuntu?

For example, if a strange person access my computer, and i can see what login and password that the strange person try to access. And i can see the time of day,week and year of that access.

I imagine to use a thing like it for me to realize who try to access my computer in my work. Because i have a coworker that know my password of my computer. It's not a problem in my actual work now, but if i use my computer in other place with other person seeing my work.

Can i do a log to store all login and password when i access my computer?

Comment: That would be quite the security hole: Any successful intruder or poisoned website could then easily learn *your* login and password.

Comment: If your coworker knows your password then change it. You can get a log of all the times you or they logged into and out of Ubuntu. Cron will email you when there are invalid passwords entered with `sudo` so I imagine a feature can be found somewhere for invalid login attempts too

Comment: If you're asking about bad login attempts, they're already logged in `/var/log/btmp` and may be viewed (if you have appropriate privileges) using the `lastb` command. See `man last`. (Passwords aren't logged - because they are hashed anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

No. Passwords should never be stored in log files.

Is there a reason why the current setup is not working for you? /var/log/ has loads and loads of log files.

3 important log files:

> **/var/log/syslog** logs generic system activity logs.
>
> **/var/log/auth.log** logs authentication related events are logged here.
>
> **/var/log/faillog** logs failed login attempts.

Comment: in faillog, show up a thing like it @^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^, it's normal?

Comment: see `man faillog`  ;)